# twig/symfony - multiple if condition

Tags: html, symfony, twig

The problem is really "simple" but hard at the same time.

So i want this

`{% if currentUrl != '/' %}`

to to also match

`'/home/index'`

Here is waht i have tried and none of it worked.

`{% if currentUrl != '/' or  currentUrl == '/home/index'%}
{% if currentUrl != '/' or  currentUrl != '/home/index'%}
{% if (currentUrl != '/') or (currentUrl != '/home/index') %}`

and some more..

is my syntax this of or why do i not get the same result as just with

`{% if currentUrl != '/' %}`

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are incorrectly using a logical OR comparison.

```
{% if currentUrl != '/' or currentUrl != '/home/index'%}
  {# it is not one of them, but it could still be the other one #}
  {# it's never both of them so this block will always render #}
{% endif %}
```

I think your intention is to perform a logical AND comparison.

```
{% if currentUrl != '/' and currentUrl != '/home/index'%}
  {# it is not one AND it is also not the other #}
  {# this block will not render if it is either of the specified urls #}
{% endif %}
```

However, in your case I would recommend using the twig `in` [Containment Operator](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#containment-operator). This performs a containment test returning true if the left operand is contained in the right. This makes more readable code, and is also easier to maintain if you decide later you need to match another url, simply add it to the array.

```
{% if currentUrl in ['/', '/home/index'] %}
  {# it's one of the urls #}
{% else %}
  {# it's a different url #}
{% endif %}
```

With `not in` returns true if the left operand is not contained in the right.

```
{% if currentUrl not in ['/', '/home/index'] %}
  {# it's a different url #}
{% else %}
  {# it's one of the urls #}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you i never knew abou the 'not in', very clean solution.